# Java string contains substring

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

java code check if the string contains substring and how many time a substring is repeated in the string with index

```java
void main() {
    int a = 0, b = 0; float b;
    cout << ;
}
```

want to separate this e.g code into its substring for example

```
{"void","main","(",")","{"}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to split the input content by whitespace? It doesn't sound like you are using the term `substring` correctly.

Comment: what if i dont have spaces in my code for example int main() then how split it

Comment: Maybe use [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp). Whitespace includes spaces, tabs, character returns, and newlines. Is your question how to split up some text by some arbitrary characters? Or are you asking how to find and count repeated non-whitespace symbols? It's a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

To break the input string into "pieces" it is better to use a regular expression to match desired parts, and then collect the results into a list.

The pattern for a regular expression might be: `\\w+|[(){}]` -- it detects "words" (e.g., reserved words, integer numbers, variable names) and each of parentheses or curly brackets; whitespaces, punctuation marks (commas, semicolons, equal signs `=`, etc.) are ignored.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\w+|[(){}]");
        
        String code = "void main() {\n\tint a = 0, b = 0; float b;\n\t    cout << ;\n}";
        
        List<String> parts = pat.matcher(code)
                                .results().map(MatchResult::group)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(parts);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[void, main, (, ), {, int, a, 0, b, 0, float, b, cout, }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use indexOf() and substring with while loop

Comment: i want to break   string into pices e.g. int main() here I can convert int and main into substring by using split by space but how I separate ( with main